# Ignore CSS of site

Tags: css

I believe this is impossible but i am hoping someone has a trick or solution.

Site A has its own HTML and CSS styles defined wants to use a third party component from Service B. Service B provides its own HTML and CSS so it can render its component.

Is there a generic way to ensure the CSS of Site A does not override or effect the CSS of Service Bs component?

Lets say Site A has the following CSS

```
 -- Site A Css
 button{
     color:#fff;
 }
```

Compoonent B has a button element but does not change the button color. So as we stand, Service Bs button will have a color of #fff.

Is there a way to to ensure that Component Bs button (and all of Component Bs other elements) **ignore** the CSS of site A.

Comment: If it is included in site A`s code, there is no chance. You will have to use an iframe (as sevenseacat already said)

Comment: How sure is ensure? `#id` + `!important` would give a specificity that makes accidental overriding unlikely.

Comment: I knew about the Iframe solution but i was hoping not to use it. in the above scenario i am the Service B. So i was hoping to allow Site A,B,C to use the Service Css in such a way that their existing CSS does not effect it BUT also that they could alter the Service B Css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an iframe :

```
 <iframe src="..third party site"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set attribute in html.

```
#button { color:#fff; }

<div id="button" style="color:red !important;"></div>
```

Comment: Well yes, but this only handles the properties you think of. (This is not to say it's a bad answer, it's a tough problem.)

Comment: Yes, it is obvious indeed.

Comment: This is a possibility BUT would require me to overwrite every possibility as ULrich said. Thanks for the answer but its wont work.